# Residence permit online application [France]

Tags: france

I applied for a "Passport Talent" visa for France. I got a Visa for 3 months (Pass. Talent VLS) and came to France. I applied for the residence permit online. I received a confirmation email of my demand, but without paying the fees (usually, 235 Euros, as I've seen on the website). How did we are supposed to pay for the residence permit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How did we are supposed to pay for the residence permit?

You pay by buying *timbres fiscaux* (revenue stamps) for €225 to prove when you get the physical card

> 6ème étape : Acheter le timbre fiscal
> Si la carte de séjour vous est attribuée, vous devez régler 225 € (droit de timbre de 25 € + taxe de 200 €) par timbres fiscaux.
> Le justificatif de paiement du droit de timbre et de la taxe est demandé lors de la remise de la carte.
> Vous pouvez acheter le timbre fiscal sur internet ou dans un bureau de tabac.

[service-public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16922)

*Translation and emphasis mine* :

> 6th step: Buy the revenue stamp
> **If you are awarded** the *carte de séjour*, you must pay €225 (stamp fee of €25 + €200 Tax) by revenue stamp
> The proof of payment of the stamp and tax is required **when you retrieve the card**.
> You can buy the revenue stamp online or in a *bureau de tabac*